# Изменить стиль тега, найденного по классу

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
var parrentCheck = document.getElementById('checkBox').parentNode;
var checkBoxes = parrentCheck.getElementsByClassName('checkBox');
var i = 1;

checkBoxes[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
checkBoxes[i].nextSibling.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Помогите советом, поскольку данный метод не работает

Comment: Можете привести код html разметки?

Comment: Создается в js в функции ранее.
www.icit223pro.meximas.com (кнопка выбрать категорию)

Comment: @Gaponec, может, у вас есть еще какие-то дополнительные условия? Я попробовал ввести ваш код в консоли на вашей же странице и элемент пропал (видимо, как и требуется) http://clip2net.com/s/ibUTDX

Comment: да, спасибо. По всем условиям пробежался - оказывается, при нажатии клавиши - выполняется создание всплывающего окна заново. Не порядок.